# angular throw error when generate new app: project name is invalid

Tags: angular

I try to create an angular app for my website:

```
ng new jon-sud.io
```

But angular throw error:

> Project name "jon-sud.io" is invalid.

I want to create angular app with the folder named `jon-sud.io`, not `jonSudIo`.

1. Why angular doesn't allow name like that?
2. How to override this and make it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular doesn't allow that format. As mentioned by @huan feng. "New project names must start with a letter, and must contain only alphanumeric characters or dashes."

However, since you want to have that specific folder name you can follow the steps below

1. ng new jonsudio
2. ren jonsudio jon-sud.io
3. cd jon-sud.io

Now you have an angular project in folder named "jon-sud.io"

Answer (score 1):

1. New project names must start with a letter, and must contain only alphanumeric characters or dashes.
2. I don't think you can override it, maybe you can ask it on angular-cli github.